# vcpkg does not use registry defined in `vcpkg-configuration.json`

Tags: vcpkg

I'm trying to use a modified version of [imgui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui) through vcpkg.

I've created a git repository to be used for the registry (https://github.com/altschuler/vcpkg-custom-ports), and copied over the imgui port configuration, and made the changes I needed (following guides like [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/registries-bring-your-own-libraries-to-vcpkg/) and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/registries.md#configuration-registries)).

However, **vcpkg seems to ignore the entry for the custom repo** in `vcpkg-configuration.json`, it simply doesn't load anything from it (I know because I tried changing the repository url to something that doesn't exist). If I set the `default-repository` to my custom one it does load stuff, but then all the packages I want from the `builtin` registry obviously fail to install.

Note: the reason I need a custom port for imgui is that I need to compile some definitions (basically just do `target_compile_definitions` in its CMakeLists). If you know of an easier way to do that I'm all ears.

`vcpkg-configuration.json`:

```
{
  "registries": [
    {
      "kind": "git",
      "baseline": "e3b33f3a548f20ba06b2959aa3701bd50ece0638",
      "repository": "https://github.com/altschuler/vcpkg-custom-ports.git",
      "packages": ["imgui"]
    }
  ]
}
```

`vcpkg.json`:

```
{
  "name": "tester",
  "version-string": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": [
    "lager",
    "sdl2",
    {
      "name": "imgui",
      "features": ["docking-experimental", "sdl2-binding", "opengl3-binding"]
    },
    "immer",
    "cereal",
    "rxcpp",
    "range-v3",
    "glew",
    "boost"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the exact commandline that get's executed for vcpkg? Do you have VCPKG_ environment variables set? The reason I am asking is, there are vcpkg features that depend on additional commands or environment variables and perhaps vcpkg-configuration.json is one of them. Have you set the VCPGK_FEATURE_FLAGS to manifest, for example?

Comment: The command is `vcpkg install`. I'm using manifest mode yes, that's automatical when `vcpkg.json` is found I believe. I don't have any other `VCPKG_` env vars set, no, but it *is* picking up the config file, it just seems to ignore the `registries` part.

Comment: Can you post the log file where the vcpkg install commands are in? Are you using Visual Studio integration or CMake?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an environment variable

```
VCPKG_FEATURE_FLAGS=manifests,binarycaching,registries
```

AFAIK, some features are not enabled by default. Seems that manifests are automatically enabled, so `vcpkg.json` gets picked up, but perhaps "registries" are not enabled by default. (Disregard "binarycaching", if you don't use it).

This is what is working for me.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference unfortunately

Comment: How did you get the value for the "baseline" property? Did you copy the `git log` value or did you use `git rev-parse HEAD:...`?

Comment: I copied the latest commit's SHA.

Comment: It that value the same as `git rev-parse HEAD`? Does it work if you copy the `git rev-parse HEAD` value?

Comment: Wasn't the same value no, using the rev-parse HEAD value doesn't seem to change anything though. I would assume it would also at least try to connect to the registry regardless of the baseline value.